# Showing that $f(z) = \frac{z}{1+|z|}$ is holomorphic (or not)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to determin whether:

$$f(z) = \frac{z}{1+|z|}$$

is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. I'm struggling to make any progress. I can show that it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, although I'm aware that this isn't enough to show it is holomorphic

Any tips would be much appreciated

Comment: what can you say about $|f(z)|$?. also: a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33346/proving-fracz1z-is-holomorphic-nowhere?rq=1

Comment: @Wooster can you type up your work for showing that $f$ satisfies the Cauchy--Riemann equations?

Comment: Oh on more careful calculation, I see they are not satisfied! Thanks for bringing that to my attention!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic. Denote $g(z) =|z|$ then $g(z) =\frac{z-f(z)}{f(z)}$ should be holomorphic but this is not true.

Answer (score 3):

$$|f(z)|=\frac{|z|}{1+|z|}<1$$

Since $f$ is bounded and not constant, by Liouville's Theorem, can't be holomorphic.

Comment: This only shows that $f$ can't be holomorphic everywhere. (In fact, it is nowhere holomorphic.)